# How to get TOTAL DAYS from two dates (one in sql database and then todays date (system date))

Tags: javascript, php

Need to show total days in html table.

I have the first date in myhpadmin table [CREATED_AT] and then todays date (not in database).
Only what to show the total days in my html table, when I open the webpage.

Did get the script code from searching , but it does not show the info at all.

Not sure how to use print in the script

```
<td>
<?php $date = $checkSqlRow["DAYS_OLD"]; ?></td>
    <script>
            $date1 = $date = $checkSqlRow["CREATED_AT"];
            $date2 = today;
            $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
            $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
            $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
            $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));


            printf("%d days\n", $days);
```

Comment: Why is this in script tags? Also, why not use `echo $days;`?

Comment: You forgot to re-open your PHP tags to run the second PHP part. Even then, you'd be outputting the value into a `<script>` tag which is supposed to contain client-side JavaScript code, so you still wouldn't see it unless you examine the raw source of the page - and it wouldn't form a valid JavaScript block.

Comment: What is a  "myhpadmin table"? Do you mean MySQL table (PhpMyAdmin isn't a database, it's a web appliction for querying MySQL).

Comment: @geertjanknapen   If I take out the script tags, it show the page full of data outside the table, I di try <?php echo $days; ?>, and still not showing.

Comment: @Barmar   yes it is mysql table

Comment: @ADyson   Is there a other way to show it in html table

Comment: Even if you remove the `<script>` tag, you're echoing it outside of any table cell, which invalidates the table structure. You need to open another `<td>` and output it into that. (P.S. In the longer term, learn about templating engines and get out of the habit of intermixing HTML and PHP to this extent.)

Answer (score 0):

With help from someone, it is working! within the td

```
td>
                                    <?php $date = $checkSqlRow["DAYS_OLD"]; ?>
                                    <?php
                                    $date1 = $date = $checkSqlRow["CREATED_AT"];
                                    $date2 =  date("y-m-d"); // this returns today's date
                                    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
                                    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
                                    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
                                    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
                                    echo $years . " Jare -- \n";
                                    echo $months . " Maande -- \n";
                                    echo $days . " Dae\n";
                                    
                                    
                                    ?>
                                    </td>
```

Comment: share the solution to others.